# Extracting data from XML Array using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following XML and would like to extract the PrimaryTeams, SecondaryTeams and OverflowTeams arrays from this and either have them comma separated or one per row.

I have the following xml:

```
declare @xml xml 
set @xml = '<SimpleStrategy xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Synthesys.Switch.ACD">
  <Id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Id>
  <Name>Default</Name>
  <AcceptedCLIs xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:string>07811353995</d2p1:string>
  </AcceptedCLIs>
  <ActiveHours>
    <FridayEnd />
    <FridayStart />
    <MondayEnd />
    <MondayStart />
    <SaturdayEnd />
    <SaturdayStart />
    <SundayEnd />
    <SundayStart />
    <ThursdayEnd />
    <ThursdayStart />
    <TuesdayEnd />
    <TuesdayStart />
    <UseIndividualWeekDays>false</UseIndividualWeekDays>
    <WednesdayEnd />
    <WednesdayStart />
    <WeekdayEnd />
    <WeekdayStart />
  </ActiveHours>
  <AgentUserName />
  <AllowRouteDuringFinalMessage>false</AllowRouteDuringFinalMessage>
  <CRMPrefix />
  <DirectDDIMessage />
  <DirectDDIPassThrough>false</DirectDDIPassThrough>
  <EmergencyBusyBack>false</EmergencyBusyBack>
  <EmergencyDivertNumber />
  <EmergencyWavFile />
  <FinallyDivertNumber />
  <FinallyDrop>true</FinallyDrop>
  <FinallyMessageFile />
  <MaximumQueueLength>0</MaximumQueueLength>
  <MaximumQueueWait>0</MaximumQueueWait>
  <MinimumRingTime>4000</MinimumRingTime>
  <MusicOnHold />
  <MusicWhileWaiting />
  <NumberOfRings>2</NumberOfRings>
  <OutOfHoursDivertNumber />
  <OutOfHoursDrop>true</OutOfHoursDrop>
  <OutOfHoursMessage />
  <OverflowMessage />
  <OverflowTeams xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
  <PrimaryTeams xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:int>3</d2p1:int>
    <d2p1:int>1</d2p1:int>
  </PrimaryTeams>
  <Priority>1</Priority>
  <RecordAgent>false</RecordAgent>
  <RecordCall>true</RecordCall>
  <RecordCustomer>false</RecordCustomer>
  <RegulatoryMessage>Default.wav</RegulatoryMessage>
  <SecondaryOverflowMessage />
  <SecondaryTeams xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
  <SendBusyIfQueueTooLong>false</SendBusyIfQueueTooLong>
  <SendBusyIfWaitTooLong>false</SendBusyIfWaitTooLong>
  <TimeInOverflow>-1</TimeInOverflow>
  <TimeWithDirectDDI>20000</TimeWithDirectDDI>
  <TimeWithPrimaryTeams>-1</TimeWithPrimaryTeams>
  <TimeWithSecondaryTeams>20000</TimeWithSecondaryTeams>
  <UseDirectDDI>false</UseDirectDDI>
  <UsePAM>false</UsePAM>
  <UseSecondaryTeams>false</UseSecondaryTeams>
  <WrapTime>40000</WrapTime>
</SimpleStrategy>'
```

I then created the following SQL Statement to try and extract the Teams

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' as d2p1,
                     DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Synthesys.Switch.ACD')

SELECT @xml,
    @xml.value('(/SimpleStrategy/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
    @xml.value('(/SimpleStrategy/PrimaryTeams)[1]', 'int') as PrimaryTeams,
    @xml.value('(/SimpleStrategy/SecondaryTeams)[1]', 'int') as SecondaryTeams,
    @xml.value('(/SimpleStrategy/OverflowTeams)[1]', 'int') as OverflowTeams
```

But all I get is the TeamID's concatenated together.

,PrimaryTeams,SecondaryTeams,OverflowTeams

Default,31,0,0

Any ideas?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: It's not clear what you want your final result set to look like (the number of teams are different in each case), but as a hint, try `SELECT n.i.value('.', 'int') FROM @xml.nodes('/SimpleStrategy/PrimaryTeams/d2p1:int') as n(i)`.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect, I can run with this to get what I need, :)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML shows two team IDs in `<PrimaryTeams>`, while both other team nodes are empty... You did not tell us anything about the expected counts in there. However, the following approach will return a kind of *entity-value-pairs* with all IDs for all Teams. Hope this is what you need:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' as d2p1,
                     DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Synthesys.Switch.ACD')

SELECT 'Name' AS Caption
      ,1 AS RowInx
      ,@xml.value('(/SimpleStrategy/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Content
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Primary Team'
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      ,t.value('.','varchar(255)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/SimpleStrategy/PrimaryTeams/d2p1:int') A(t)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Secondary Team'
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      ,t.value('.','varchar(255)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/SimpleStrategy/SecondaryTeams/d2p1:int') A(t)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Overflow-Team'
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      ,t.value('.','varchar(255)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/SimpleStrategy/OverflowTeams/d2p1:int') A(t);
```